# Working with semirings in Coq

Tags: coq

This is a simple Coq syntax newbie question.:)

I am trying to define simple polynomial function on semi_rings:

```
Require Import Vector.
Import VectorNotations.
Require Import Ring_theory.

Section Polynomial_def.
       Variable Asring : Type.
       Variable (asr_0 asr_1 : Asring) (asr_add asr_mul: Asring->Asring->Asring).
       Variable SRth : semi_ring_theory asr_0 asr_1 asr_add asr_mul eq.

       Fixpoint evalPolynomial {n} (a: t Asring n) (x:Asring) : Asring  :=
        match a with
            nil => asr_0
          | cons a0 p a' => asr_add a0 (asr_mul x (evalPolynomial a' x))
        end.        
    End Polynomial_def.
```

When I use it on Reals, for example, I have to do something like this:

```
 Require Import Reals.Rdefinitions.

 evalPolynomial R R0 Rplus Rmult a v
```

I suspect there should be a simpler syntax, where I can just pass single data structure (like `comm_ring_1` in Isabelle) which will encapsulate all fields like R,R0,Rplus,Rmult for given type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can package all of your parameters in a structure and then pass that as an argument, something like

```
Structure semiring := Semiring {
  Asring : Type;
  asr_0 : Asring;
  asr_1 : Asring;
  asr_add : Asring -> Asring -> Asring
  (* Other fields... *)
}.
```

Then, you can rephrase your development in terms of this structure:

```
Section Polynomial_def.
Variable sr := semiring.

Fixpoint evalPolynomial {n} (a: t (Asring sr) n) (x:Asring sr) : Asring sr :=
(* ... *)
```

Later, when trying to use that, you just have to build such a structure and pass it as a normal argument. You can also use Coq type classes or canonical structures to tell Coq how to pass such arguments automatically.

Comment: Do I need to use `semi_ring_theory`?

Comment: I hadn't thought about Coq's own `semi_ring_theory`, as I don't tend to need that very much. My guess is that it would probably be useful to go for that, as those can be used with the `ring` family of tactics, and thus will help you automate your proofs.

Comment: Would it be better to add semi_ring_theory as part of this structure to ensure that each instance of this structure will support this theory? Right now I can throw into this structure values which would not make a ring.

Comment: Yes, or you can just use `semi_ring_theory` on its own, since most of the functionality you need will probably be there already.